# Loading Partials with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I would like to load my partials when needed? For instance, I have a partial which consists of 6 thumbnails, and when clicking on one it loads my partial, please let me know?

Comment: The default behavior is that the partial isn't loaded until a specific url is hit.

Comment: if you had simply looked in your browser console network tab you would have already known

Comment: You seem to be a bit in the dark what you are trying to do or ask. Angular is a client side application framework. Not another jquery. Consider following the angular tutorials and especially the one about Routing and Multiple views, relating to your question: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Answer (score -1):

You need to use routing to do this.  Here's a [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) but the basic setup is this:

HTML - This will have several `<a>` anchor tags that each contain their respective routes, like so:

```
  <ul class="phones">
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp" class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}"></a>
      <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Then you need to make sure you're setting up your app to use `ngRoute`:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
]);
```

Then setup the `routeProvider` in your config:

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

This directs each of the chunks in the `ng-repeat` to use a partial defined in the `templateUrl`.

Of course you also have to define behavior in your controller but this should get you started on basic routing.

Comment: Mind commenting on the downvote?  Does this not answer the question?  It's not like I ripped off the tutorial, I linked it